# Is this an American Basswood?

Tags: identification, trees

Asking for a friend. I have not seen the tree in person. The leaves look so much like [*Tilia americana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilia_americana) to me, but the bark doesn't look quite like what I'm used to. I also didn't notice any bracts in the pictures. Does anyone confirm the ID?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a basswood tree, which makes [great lettuce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v69QDpgUFuY) from its leaves for salads :P

When I was at an herbalists guild garden walk they completely understood what I was saying when eating tree leaves.

Comment: Is your tongue smiley supposed to denote sarcasm? Is it truly edible? Any reference for that or the verification of identification?

Comment: I'm licking my lips in the emoji